# NullPointerException when recording jmeter test plan

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'm getting below exception in jMeter 5.4.3 when recording Test Plan:

```
2022-02-01 20:59:35,150 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [64794]  Exception when processing sample
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState$9.process(HtmlTreeBuilderState.java:934) ~[jsoup-1.13.1.jar:?]
    at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.process(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:141) ~[jsoup-1.13.1.jar:?]
    at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState$14.anythingElse(HtmlTreeBuilderState.java:1227) ~[jsoup-1.13.1.jar:?]
    at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState$14.process(HtmlTreeBuilderState.java:1191) ~[jsoup-1.13.1.jar:?]
    at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.process(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:136) ~[jsoup-1.13.1.jar:?]
    at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState$10.process(HtmlTreeBuilderState.java:1019) ~[jsoup-1.13.1.jar:?]
    at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.process(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:136) ~[jsoup-1.13.1.jar:?]
    at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.runParser(TreeBuilder.java:66) ~[jsoup-1.13.1.jar:?]
    at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:47) ~[jsoup-1.13.1.jar:?]
    at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:107) ~[jsoup-1.13.1.jar:?]
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:58) ~[jsoup-1.13.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.FormCharSetFinder.addFormActionsAndCharSet(FormCharSetFinder.java:55) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.addFormEncodings(Proxy.java:629) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:250) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3]
2022-02-01 20:59:35,153 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [64794]  Exception while writing error
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeBytes(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.writeErrorToClient(Proxy.java:580) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:269) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3]
2022-02-01 20:59:40,717 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder stopped
```

When it happens the browser stops loading the page and its console shows:

```
net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal server error)
```

The browsers are Chrome 97.0.4692.99 and Firefox 91.5.1esr.
During regular use, without jMeter Proxy recorder, the web page behaves normally. Can't see anything bad in the web server logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have never faced issue like this so it might be connected with a problem in your application, check console tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) for any suspicious entries.

In any case an unhandled [NPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) looks like a bug to me, even if it's not in JMeter but in the 3rd-party libraries, I would expect that on page charset detection failure there should be a fallback to some default, either current locale or UTF-8 so I would recommend raising it via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html).

In the meantime you can consider using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) for recording, it's not that invasive and should handle

Comment: I filed a bug to jMeter: [https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65864](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65864) . Will check further the web console and next try this extension.